# Visualise HBase inside Hdinsight (Azure)

Tags: azure, hbase

Can Anyone help me How to visualize data stored in HBase inside HDInsight.
Any tool or Web browser on Windows or Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure PowerBI is the way to go 
Just follow the steps in this article.
Basically you just connect your HDInsight with the PowerBI using Apache Spark for HDInsight
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/powerbi/archive/2015/07/14/visualize-big-data-with-power-bi-and-spark-for-azure-hdinsight.aspx

Comment: Thanks for reply ................ I checked .. But not able to connect... I think it is for connecting to Spark. But I want to connect to HBase....